# Unmanaged 32bit dll in C# wcf service could not load on IIS 7 using system.dynamic

Tags: .net, wcf, iis-7, com, unmanaged

I have an unmanaged c dll, which is register under class_root registry. it it 32bit and register on x64 bit windows server r2.

I have developed a wcf application which load c dll from registry value like

```
 Type type= Type.GetTypeFromProgID("cdllregistyassociatedkey");                     
            dynamic typeobj= Activator.CreateInstance(type,true);
          // call c dll function with typeobj here....
```

its work fine during development and debugging with vs2012 .net 4.0. but when I deploye the service on IIS 7. c dll couldn't load and throw exception.

like

```
Activator.CreateInstance(type,bool) 
type could n't be null
```

Any one can help please. thanks in advance

Comment: Is IIS running a 64-bit application pool?

Comment: YEs IIS is running on 64bit machine/os. but I have enabled Pool for 32bit application

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the machine is 64 bit or not. You have to ensure that the pool is indeed 32 bit.

Comment: POOL is enable for 32bit.

Comment: What you see in settings doesn't matter. Is the process where the pool is running indeed 32 bit?

Comment: it is the response from IIS: <p>The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is: </p>
      <p>   at ManagedCS.ManagedCodeService.LoadData(Stream data)
   at SyncInvokeLoadData(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]&amp; outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)